# If $u\in C^1(I)\cap L^p(I)$ and $u' \in L^p(I)$, then $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to prove a claim made on Brezis' "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDE's", that if $I=(a,b)$ is an interval (bounded or unbouded), $u\in C^1(I)\cap L^p(I)$ and $u' \in L^p(I)$ (classical derivative), then $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ and the weak derivative coincides with the classical one.

My attempt: if $\varphi \in C_c^1(I)$, then in particular $u\varphi \in C^1(I)$. Then, differentiating the product we get
$$u\varphi'=(u\varphi)'-u'\varphi$$
Integrating, we get
$$\int_I u\varphi'=\int_I(u\varphi)'-\int_Iu'\varphi $$
But I cannot use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on the second integral to write $\int_a^b(u\varphi)'=u(b)\varphi(b)-u(a)\varphi(a)$, because these functions are defined only on $(a,b)$. I have a feel that somehow the second integral must vanish, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: $\varphi$ is of compact support in $(a,b)$, it must banish on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: But, at first, $\varphi$ is defined only on $(a,b)$. Are you talking about an extension of $\varphi$ to $[a,b]$, then?

Comment: Because the support is compact you may extend $\varphi$ as 0 elsewhere, notice that for $b-x < \frac{d(b,\text{supp}(\varphi))}{2}$ then $x \notin \text{supp}{\varphi}$ so $\varphi$ banishes in a neighborhood of $b$.